# Android Debug Output Button Messages

Tags: java, android, debugging, button, output

I'm currently developing a test android application, and something that I noticed in the debug message after clicking a button is quite many lines of

> D/OpenGLRenderer: DisplayEventReceiver 0x7f72335040 requestNextVsync
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: DisplayEventReceiver 0x7f72335040 latestVsyncEvent 875611520846106

I was just wondering if anyone knows what these mean or if it's anything I should worry about?

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but android internally post out some debug information. You do not need to care about it.